# SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length when modifying request with fiddler

Tags: c#, ssl, fiddler, fiddlercore

I'm trying to implement a in-system SSL server using FiddlerCore:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace fiddlerCoreTest
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Threading;
    using Fiddler;

    class Program
    {
        static Proxy oSecureEndpoint;
        static string sSecureEndpointHostname = "localhost";
        static int iSecureEndpointPort = 7777;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //var tt = Fiddler.CertMaker.GetRootCertificate().GetRawCertData();
            //File.WriteAllBytes("root.crt",tt);

            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += delegate(Fiddler.Session oS)
            {
                oS.bBufferResponse = false;               

                if ((oS.hostname == sSecureEndpointHostname)&&oS.port==7777)
                {
                    oS.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
                    oS.oResponse.headers.HTTPResponseStatus = "200 Ok";
                    oS.oResponse["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
                    oS.oResponse["Cache-Control"] = "private, max-age=0";
                    oS.utilSetResponseBody("<html><body>Request for httpS://" + sSecureEndpointHostname + ":" + iSecureEndpointPort.ToString() + " received. Your request was:<br /><plaintext>" + oS.oRequest.headers.ToString());
                }
            };

            FiddlerCoreStartupFlags oFCSF = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default;
            oFCSF = (oFCSF & ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy);

            Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, oFCSF);

            oSecureEndpoint = FiddlerApplication.CreateProxyEndpoint(iSecureEndpointPort, true, sSecureEndpointHostname);
            if (null != oSecureEndpoint)
            {
                FiddlerApplication.Log.LogFormat("Created secure end point listening on port {0}, using a HTTPS certificate for '{1}'", iSecureEndpointPort, sSecureEndpointHostname);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

in firefox, GET `http://localhost:7777/` works fine, but when I GET `https://localhost:7777/` , firefox reports following error:

[image: SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length]

Why do I get this, and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**
This happens only when I use fiddler as the proxy with firefox. When I remove fiddler proxy,  I can access `https://localhost:7777/` . However, I would also like to be able to access `https://localhost:7777/` via proxy

Comment: Let's back up a little bit. When Fiddler *isn't* set as the proxy in Firefox, can you visit https://localhost:7777? Also, what's the exact version of Firefox that you're using? Does a breakpoint on utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer ever get hit?

Comment: I'm using ff17.0.1 . When I visit `https://localhost:7777` without proxy, it works. `oS.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();` gets hit, and the function returns a response to fiddler core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this scenario is that you're processing this traffic twice:

First, the browser sends a CONNECT to port 8888 saying: "Please give me a TCP/IP tunnel to port 7777" and then after Fiddler says "Okay, we'll do that" the client sends a HTTPS request through that tunnel to port 7777.

The problem here is that you're mangling that CONNECT response and returning HTML instead of allowing the HTTPS handshake from port 7777 to flow through.

The simplest way to fix this would be to change your BeforeRequest code to the following:

```
if ( (oS.hostname == sSecureEndpointHostname) && (oS.port==7777)
    && !oS.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT")) {
```

After you do this, your CONNECT tunnel will no longer be getting mangled and the HTTPS handshake will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS traffic is encrypted and fiddler as a web debugger proxy cannot decrypt/analyze packet data being sent through fiddler. It uses a MITM attack to decrypt SSL traffic being sent via fiddler, see here:
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp

So you have to enable SSL option in fiddler, then re-check it. If it doesn't worked, try to provide a manual MITM certificate to fiddler.

Comment: fiddler decrypts the ssl traffic ok. but when I'm trying to modify it, I'm getting this error

Comment: Fiddler should allow you to modify the packet and the inner information; if you wish.  It is supposed to have Fiddler Injector property that you can configure.

Comment: well, in my experience it lets me modify http requests just fine, and fails on https requests with this  error

Comment: could you use same certificate in your fiddler and web server?